# No class files are created in WEB-INF

Tags: java, eclipse, export, war

I have two eclipse projects.

When I give export to war, one project is exported successfully.

But the latter one is not. No class files are created in WEB-INF/classes/packagename.

Please help me. I searched over net. But nothing is helpful to me.

Comment: Sorry. Now I got the issue. When I copied the project from one system to another, the referenced library path made the issue. But no error showed in the code.. :(

Comment: clean,build. also check your project path does not contain any white space. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the "Java Build Path"  and "Project Facets" is set properly .
Try clean the project and click "Build Automatically" twice .
If you provide the Java Build Path and Project Facets ,maybe you can get more detailed help.